# How to write regex to remove whitespace between tag and words for HTMl minifier

Tags: javascript, html, regex, node.js, minify

I am building a very simple HTML minifier. So far so good.

`var file = process.argv[2],`
    `html = "",`
    `fs = require("fs");`

```
html = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
string = html.replace(/\n/g, "");
var x = string.replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<");
var y = x.replace(/\>[\t ]+\</g, "><");
var z = y.replace(/\>[\t ]+$/g, ">");

console.log(z)
```

returns string: `<div id="hello"><p class="new">            Hello</p></div>`

How do I write a regex to get rid of any space that will appear between words and tags (before and after)? Should return: `<div id="hello"><p class="new">Hello</p></div>`

Comment: Try `str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Comment: @Tushar actually, this does not work they way I need it. it is removing all white space including the space between a tag and it's attribute

Comment: That's why you need the space as the second param of `replace`

Comment: That's because, presumably, there's a newline before `Hello`. Newline also matches as `\s+` and therefore is replaced with space. Face it, regular expressions cannot and should not be used for XML/HTML manipulation. Instead, load HTML into DOM parser and then replace in text nodes only, so that you don't break HTML structure or create other kinds of mess.

Comment: Tushar's regex is wrong. I don't even know why people are upvoting it. It will replace all white space (multiple or otherwise) with a single space. That is incorrect and not what OP asked for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/361684

Comment: You **need** to retain the space before "Hello" unless you want to change the meaning of the HTML.

Comment: @torazaburo You do not *need* to retain the space before "Hello" at all, and in fact OP specifically provided an example showing he does not want any of the preceding whitespace retained. Moreover, whitespace between HTML tags is not HTML and cannot change the meaning of the HTML. dustmouse's answer is far more accurate because it's not messing with the text, and only affecting whitespace around HTML tags. Your regex is affecting everything including text.

Comment: I am greatly puzzled why you think whitespace would not matter. `<span> a</span>` is different from `<span>a</span>`. The former has whitespace which will be rendered. Furthermore, your assertion that "whitespace between HTML tags is not HTML" is wrong. Text within HTML is very much HTML, and whitespace between HTML tags is part of a text node within the DOM. Yes, runs of whitespace are collapsed, so two spaces in a row are rendered as one; but that is different from saying that whitespace does not matter, or that an HTML minifier is allowed to eliminate all whitespace between tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var html = '<div id="hello"><p class="new">            Hello  friend  </p></div>';

var result = html.replace(/>\s+|\s+</g, function(m) {
    return m.trim();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gbhhh25/

**It will only remove spaces between a tag and a word (opening and closing).**  So it won't affect text in tags or spaces between text.

**torazaburo** makes a good point about a potential pitfall in OP's requirements where a single space is required to preserve the structure of the text.  So **Tushar**'s solution of `str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');` would work perfectly in that case.

Comment: The `trim` part is redundant because any spaces before or after the first and last tags will be replaced by your regex anyway.

Comment: this is good solution. another good solution is Tushar's solution in the question's comments. `str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Comment: Unfortunately, this removes significant spaces. For instance, the run of spaces before "Hello" should be reduced to a single space, not removed.

Comment: @turazaburo - OP asked for >Hello<, so no spaces.

Comment: He asked for something which was wrong, which would change the meaning of the HTML, so part of a good answer would be to point that out and provide a solution which is correct.

Comment: @turazaburo - Okay, you make a good point.  I have updated my answer to consider that scenario.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5gbhhh25/1/ - removes too many spaces some times, and too few others.

Answer (score 0):

Replace any sequence of non-less-than-signs with a string which compresses multiple spaces within it to a single space:

```
str.replace(/[^<]+/g, function(match) { return match.replace(/\s+/, ' '); });

< "<div id="hello"><p class="new"> Hello</p></div>"
```

Of course, you don't want to get rid of the space before `"Hello"`, because it is meaningful.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `trim()` method to get rid of empty space without regexp.

You can find an example on the [W3Schooll web site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

See :

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```